# Expand Grouped Rows within a Group By Query

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm curious if there is a way within Oracle SQL Developer to expand the rows contained within a Group By Query whether in a report or just in the data grid.  For example, let's say I have a single Payment Transaction with a payment amount.  I have grouped these fields and I have the SUM of the items which is the total payment amount.  It would be very nice if I there was a feature that would allow me to view the items within the transaction that make up the total payment amount without having to remove the Group By fields and the Aggregate SUM function.

Using the data below as an example to show what I am looking for.  Only two tables in the below sample data.  **pymt_transactions and transaction_items**.

```
WITH pymt_transactions AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS tran_id FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 2 AS tran_id FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 3 AS tran_id FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 4 AS tran_id FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 5 AS tran_id FROM dual
) /* END pymt_transactions CTE */
--SELECT * FROM pymt_transactions;
, transaction_items AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS tran_id, 'T-Shirt' AS retail_item, 15 AS amt FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 1 AS tran_id, 'Shoes'   AS retail_item, 50 AS amt FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 1 AS tran_id, 'Pants'   AS retail_item, 40 AS amt FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 1 AS tran_id, 'Comb'    AS retail_item, 3  AS amt FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 2 AS tran_id, 'Sweater' AS retail_item, 15 AS amt FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 2 AS tran_id, 'Belt'    AS retail_item, 12 AS amt FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 2 AS tran_id, 'Pants'   AS retail_item, 40 AS amt FROM dual UNION
  SELECT 2 AS tran_id, 'Watch'   AS retail_item, 23 AS amt FROM dual
) /* END transaction_items CTE */

SELECT pt.tran_id, ti.retail_item, ti.amt
FROM pymt_transactions pt
  LEFT JOIN transaction_items ti ON ti.tran_id = pt.tran_id
ORDER BY pt.tran_id
;
```

The above produces the below result set.

[image]

Now for the Grouped By version.  Using the same two CTE's in the above example:

```
SELECT pt.tran_id, COUNT(ti.retail_item) AS num_retail_items, 
NVL(SUM(ti.amt),0) AS payment_amount
FROM pymt_transactions pt
  LEFT JOIN transaction_items ti ON ti.tran_id = pt.tran_id
GROUP BY pt.tran_id
ORDER BY pt.tran_id
;
```

The above Grouped By Query produces the below results and groups by tran_id:

[image]

Again, without my having to write two different queries is there a way I can simply have a Group By query and provide the ability to just click to expand in order to view the retail_items?  I've used reports and other systems that have this feature.  In both transaction 1 and transaction 2 there are four Retail Items.  I want to view these items without having to remove the Group By Clause and the Aggregate SUM Function that is producing the total in the payment_amount column.

Comment: the reports feature in SQLDev, you could have a report that shows the roll-ups up top and the details down below - but nothing in SQL Developer worksheet or grid in general that gives you this feature out-of-the-box

Comment: Perfect.  I just created a report.  Never used this feature.  Added the Child Report that consisted of the items.  Not as cool as say simply clicking on a plus icon and expanding the multiple items under the record being selected but it does get me what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building a report.

[image]
View > Reports.

User Defined Reports.

Add a new report.

Provide the main SQL, then go and add a child report, and tie the data together with a :BIND.

Then click on a row up top, and get the detail data you want below.
[image]

You can start to have fun with Charts if you'd like too.

Comment: I've now become very familiar with the Reports feature in SQL Developer.  I've read some of your blogs and I was certainly one of those people who have used SQL Developer for eight years now and I have never used the Reports Feature.  While there are some clunky aspects of the Reports Feature it has provided me with what I was needing.

Answer (score 1):

Having access to all the values at once, maybe this can be a solution?

```
SELECT pt.tran_id
, ti.retail_item
, ti.amt
,COUNT(ti.retail_item) over (Partition by pt.tran_id)
,SUM(ti.amt)  over (Partition by pt.tran_id)
FROM pymt_transactions pt
  LEFT JOIN transaction_items ti ON ti.tran_id = pt.tran_id
ORDER BY pt.tran_id
;
```

Comment: While that is possible this answer still leaves you with the same issue - readability.  For example, I have 851 individual transactions for a specific date range.  I want to see these individual transactions so I can make sense of it.  If I include within the same query ALL of the items that are inside these 851 transactions I now have an extremely large data set.  This now becomes very difficult to inspect or make sense of.  3 items per transaction = 2,553 rows to visually look through.

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets try to build a drill down report.
First build a user defind report calcualting the sum adding a filter (I beleive capital letters are important here)
[image]

Then add another report with your initial sql.
[image]

And add a reference to the sumcnt report
[image]

Now running the top report and right click it you will get this:
[image]

good luck